# java.lang.ClassCastException cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have MainActivity class which have method which instantiate ApplicationBar, all other Activities are inherited form this `MainActivity` so they can use this method.

But I also have a class MapHolder which has to be extended from `FragmentActivity` as in xml it uses a `fragment` to display map. The issue is if I extend it from `FragmentActivity` I cannot display ApplicationBar Tabs and if I extend it from MainActivity than I can't display maps and it gives this error:

`LogCat Output:`

```
    09-29 17:52:10.107: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(3788): Google Play services is invalid. Cannot recover.
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mydomain.myproj/com.mydomain.myproj.MapHolder }: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at com.mydomain.myproj.MapHolder .onCreate(MapHolder .java:19)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     ... 11 more
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
09-29 17:52:43.536: E/AndroidRuntime(3832):     ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to cast a `SupportMapFragment` to be a native API Level 11 `android.app.Fragment`. That will not work. Either:

- Set your `android:minSdkVersion` to 11 or higher, and use `MapFragment` instead of `SupportMapFragment`, or
- Cast your `SupportMapFragment` to be an `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

> The issue is if I extend it from FragmentActivity I cannot display ApplicationBar Tabs

The action bar was added to Android in API Level 11. If you wish to use an action bar on older versions of Android, you will need to use a backport, either [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) or [the AppCompat backport in the Android Support package](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Comment: tried option # 1 but now i am getting this error: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: @Maven: `SupportMapFragment` goes with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. `MapFragment` goes with `android.app.Fragment`. You cannot mix and match these.

Comment: I am sorry but i am new to this hence confused how do specify which goes to where currently what i am doing is specying `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` in the `fragment` tag in xml and extending the class from `FragmentActivity`, please tell which one i should change?

Comment: @Maven: If your `android:minSdkVersion` is set to 10 or below, change `MapFragment` to `SupportMapFragment`. If your `android:minSdkVersion` is set to 11 or higher, change `FragmentActivity` to `Activity`.

Comment: worked! atleast this error has gone. :D .
One lest question for my knowledge, so from 11+ `FragmentActivity` and `Activity` class are combined?

Comment: @Maven: `Activity`, as of API Level 11, has the ability to work with fragments and loaders. `Activity` on older devices did not. `FragmentActivity` is part of a "backport" of fragments and loaders to work on older devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment your activity must extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity instead of android.app.Activity